# Canvas on a frame not being displayed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `Canvas` inside a `Frame` in tkinter. The frame has a background color and the canvas too. But seemingly the frame background overrides the canvas color.

How can I increase the transparency of the frame background such that the canvas is visible?

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *


top = Tkinter.Tk()

frame = Frame(top, width=1000, height=1000, background="bisque")
frame.pack()

bottomframe = Frame(top, width=1000, height=1000, background="red")
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )


def creatLayers(no_of_layers, max_nodes_in_each_layer, frame1=bottomframe):
    print 'here2'

    listLayerRect=[]
    listDelimiterRect=[]

    #The canvas is created here.
    mainCanvas=Tkinter.Canvas(frame1, bg="white", height=1000, width=1000)
    frame1.pack(side=LEFT)

    for i in range (0,no_of_layers):            
        print 'here3'

        x=15*i

        #rectangles that are being drawn on the canvas.
        mainCanvas.create_polygon(x,0,x+10,0,x+10,1000,x,1000, outline='gray', fill='gray', width=2)

#        listLayerRect.append(Tkinter.Canvas(frame1, bg="blue", height=1000, width=30))
#        listDelimiterRect.append(Tkinter.Canvas(frame1, bg="yellow", height=1000, width=30))


L1 = Label(frame, text="Layers")
E1 = Entry(frame, bd =8)
L2 = Label(frame, text="Layers2")

def helloCallBack(E=E1,):
   # tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")
   k=int(E.get())
   print 'here'
   print k

   creatLayers(k,k)      

B = Tkinter.Button(frame, text ="Enter", command = helloCallBack)

B.pack(side=LEFT)
#L1.pack(side=LEFT)
E1.pack(side=LEFT)
#L2.pack(side=LEFT)

top.mainloop()
```

So, basically, when you enter a number in the box and press `Enter`, a canvas gets created in the red part (frame) and a *grid pattern* should be drawn on that canvas. Essentially, there are 2 frames, the top frame contains the button and the entry box, the lower frame should be able to draw stuff inside on the canvas created within.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the canvas is not displayed is because you're not telling it to be displayed inside `frame1`, i.e. you forgot to `pack` (or `grid`, or `place`) it, so just do in the meantime:

```
...
mainCanvas=Tkinter.Canvas(frame1, bg="white", height=1000, width=1000)
mainCanvas.pack()
...
```

Now depending on what you really want to achieve from the layout point of view, you may need to think better how to use `pack`, `grid` and `pack`.

Here's the result after the correction above (on Mac OS X, Sierra)

#### Before clicking `Enter`

[image]

#### After clicking `Enter`

[image]

In general, just remember that a frame will have a empty body if it doesn't contain any widget with a certain specified size.

Comment: It says: *"how to use `pack`, `grid` and `pack`."* But perhaps on of the `pack` is meant to be `place` or something else?